# Can we trust on backup tools Which is provided by Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, backup, tools

I want to take daily basic backup of database and Website. So Can I trust Magento inbuilt tools? Here is the path

> System->Tools->Backups

what are the possible reasons behind it to not take backup using Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Actually when we take back up from the tools provided by magento.

It may arise issue of some time out, or similar server related issue.
It may stop mysql or webserver service while backup.

Rather to use SSH command line, it is much faster and secure way

Not recommended for large DB or files.
Thanks